# Windows update - Please help me finding these files

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I can't update my windows 7 because of 3 missing files (says the System update readiness tool):

```
servicing\packages\Package_152_for_KB3022345~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2.mum
servicing\packages\Package_152_for_KB3022345~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.2.cat
```

and the manifest file:

```
winsxs\manifests\amd64_tsgenericusbdriver.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_7.1.7601.16398_none_8990d94eb5ecd1da. manifest
```

I think I might be able to find the manifest but I can't find the cat/mum file as the KB3022345 is not available anymore on the windows catalog... (and I also get an error when I try to remove KB3022345)

So if you happen to have any of these files on your computer or the KB3022345.msu please send me a download link, it would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT:

*I did run the stock update troubleshooter (which tells me it cannot fix the problem)

*I know KB3022345 has been superseeded but I can't uninstall it so I need to repair it first

Comment: Run the Microsoft Update Troubleshooter to fix this. Follow all the steps:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058

Comment: Why are you looking for files from 4+ years ago?  Microsoft deliberately retires patches when they are superseded by another patch.  KB3022345 no longer exists in the Microsoft Update Catalog for this reason.

Comment: @Pimpoum - Have go through all the manual methods to repair the problem.  Automatic tools are not always the best way to solve a problem like this.  We are not going to be able to provide Microsoft files to you.  You should edit your question to indicate what error you receive when you attempt to remove the update.